# Compute trigram probability from bigrams probabilities

Tags: artificial-intelligence, probability, n-gram

Given `bigram probabilities` for words in a text, how would one compute `trigram probabilities`?

For example, if we know that `P(dog cat) = 0.3` and `P(cat mouse) = 0.2`

how do we find the probability of `P(dog cat mouse)`?

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It's unlikely to be a good estimator of true trigram probability. There might never even be a third word after `dog cat`, there just no way to tell from probabilities based "given two words, this combination occurs X out of Z times"

Comment: I understand that it is not a good way to get a trigram's probability, but is there some way to estimate the probability given 2 bigrams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following I consider a trigram as three random variables `A,B,C`. So `dog cat horse` would be `A=dog, B=cat, C=horse`.

Using the chain rule: `P(A,B,C) = P(A,B) * P(C|A,B)`. Now your stuck if you want to stay exact.

What you can do is assuming `C` is independent of `A` given `B`. Then it holds that `P(C|A,B) = P(C|B)`. And `P(C|B) = P(C,B) / P(B)`, which you should be able to compute from your trigram frequencies. Note that in your case `P(C|B)` should really be the probability of `C` *following* a `B`, so it's the probability of a `BC` divided by the probability of a `B*`.

So to sum it up, when using the conditional independence assumption:

```
P(ABC) = P(AB) * P(BC) / P(B*)
```

And to compute `P(B*)` you have to sum up the probabilities for all trigrams beginning with `B`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will mark as best answer, I just have a question. So it's P(B,C)/P(B), right? But why is A's probability not used there?

Comment: Because it's only for `P(C|B)`. All add to the answer.